# Is the following std::queue code example thread safe?

Tags: c++, queue, thread-safety, mutex

I have the following code example and I'm not sure if it is thread safe.

```
void remove(/*...*/) {
    int a;
    float* data;

    while (true)
    {
        unique_lock<mutex> lock1(mu);
        cond.wait(lock1, [this](){return count > 0;});
        lock1.unlock();

        a = std_queue1.front();

        data = std_queue2.front();

        // process data

        unique_lock<mutex> lock2(mu);
        std_queue1.pop();
        std_queue2.pop();
        count--;
        lock2.unlock();
        cond.notify_all();
    }
}

void add(/*...*/){
    int a, iterations = 0;
    vector<float*> data;
    // Allocate some data entries
    while (true) {
        // set a
        unique_lock<mutex> lock1(mu);
        std_queue1.push(a);
        cond.wait(lock1, [this, &limit]() { return count < limit; });
        lock1.unlock();

        // Init data

        if (iterations++ > 2) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lock2(mu);
            std_queue2.push(data[/*...*/]);
            count++;
            lock2.unlock();
            cond.notify_all();
        }
    }
}
```

remove(...) and add(...) are functions of the same class. Each function is executed by one thread and both Threads access the same queues. A mutex is locked to push and pop data of the queues, but not for the function front().

So my question is: Is this example thread safe? Or do I need a mutex for the front() function? And is the mutex necessary for the functions pop() and push()?

Comment: `a = std_queue1.front();` isn't thread safe really, because `std_queue1.push(a);` could modify the underlying data `front` is reading in parallel. 2 parallel reads are fine however a parallel read/write could make upsetting things happen.

Comment: Looks to me like a possible deadlock. If `remove` is called when `count` is 0 then it'll hold the mutex until `count` increases. `add` can't increase the count until it gets the mutex.

Comment: @JonathanPotter: The mutex is released by the call of wait()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> So my question is: Is this example thread safe?

No.

> Or do I need a mutex for the front() function?

Yes.

> And is the mutex necessary for the functions pop() and push()?

Yes.

Modifying a standard container is not guaranteed to be thread safe.

Comment: Addendum: Remember that in addition to guarding individual operations you may have to guard the entire transaction. In between a `front` and a `pop` another thread can easily sneak in and make that `pop` a very bad idea.